# how do I allocate heap memory for the struct?

Tags: c

I have the following code

```
struct USER{

   int human_id_number;

   char first_name_letter;

   int minutes_since_sneezing;

} *administrator;
```

now I want to allocate heap memory

here's my try

```
administrator *newStruct = (administor*)malloc(sizeof(administrator));
```

not sure if this is right...

Comment: `} *administrator;` are you sure?

Comment: `administrator` is a `struct USER*`. It is a variable, not a type.

Comment: `administor*` is nothing.

Comment: @Kevin ah that's why,,any idea on fixing it?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre any idea on fixing it?

Comment: It appears you're missing `typedef` ... and, if that is true, then you have a `*` too many in the definition of `newStruct`.

Comment: Use `struct USER*` (the actual name of the type) instead and get rid of `*administrator`.

Comment: @Kevin  struct USER = (struct USER*)malloc( sizeof(struct USER) );?

Comment: check good answer below

Comment: Pay attention to the names: administrator != administor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
struct USER {
   int human_id_number;
   char first_name_letter;
   int minutes_since_sneezing;
} *administrator;
```

This isn't just a struct declaration, it's also a variable declaration... it's the same as:

```
struct USER {
   int human_id_number;
   char first_name_letter;
   int minutes_since_sneezing;
};

struct USER *administrator;
```

So, when you subsequently use `sizeof(administrator)`, you'll get "*the size of a pointer*"... which is most likely *not* what you want.

You *probably* wanted to do something more like this:

```
struct USER {
   int human_id_number;
   char first_name_letter;
   int minutes_since_sneezing;
};

int main(void) {
    struct USER *administrator;

    administrator = malloc(sizeof(*administrator));
    /* - or - */
    administrator = malloc(sizeof(struct USER));

    /* check that some memory was actually allocated */
    if (administrator == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: malloc() returned NULL...\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /* ... */

    /* don't forget to free! */
    free(administrator)

    return 0;
}
```

`sizeof(*administrator)` and `sizeof(struct USER)` will both give you "*the size of the USER structure*", and thus, the result of `malloc()` will be a pointer to enough memory to hold the structure's data.

Comment: congrats for answering this properly.

Comment: don't forget to check if malloc() failed (unlikely but...)

Comment: @Fred - I omitted it for brevity, but I've added it now.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct USER{
    int human_id_number;
    char first_name_letter;
    int minutes_since_sneezing;
} *administrator;
```

This defines administrator as a pointer variable. But, from the other code

```
administrator *newStruct = (administor*)malloc(sizeof(administrator));
```

It seems you want to use that as a type. 
To do so, you can make use of the typedef.

```
typedef struct USER{
    int human_id_number;
    char first_name_letter;
    int minutes_since_sneezing;
} administrator;
```

and then use

```
administrator *newStruct = (administrator *)malloc(sizeof(administrator));
```